# Getting all open ports on all network interfaces

Tags: linux, debian, networking, docker

I have installed and run [docker](https://www.docker.com/) and now it created another network interface **docker0**:

```
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 06:19:32:11:AD:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.xx.xx.xx/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ab90::43:2af:fe30:2245/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Even when stopping the docker service this interface is still up. How is it possible to see all open/listening ports on all interfaces (**eth0**, **wlan0** and **docker0**)? I've tried using **lsof** but I couldn't find any interface granularity options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netstat -plnt` (or the newer `ss -plnt`) will now you all listening TCP ports on your system, and which process is listening.  If not run as the superuser, you will only see the process names for processes owned by the user as whom `netstat` or `ss` is invoked.

To show UDP ports as well as TCP ports, omit the `t` switch (`netstat -pln` / `ss -pln`).

The switches used are to show `p`ports `l`istening on `t`cp `n`umerically.

Comment: But is it possible to see the interface the process is listening on?

Comment: `ip a` or `ifconfig` will show you each interface's assigned IP address(es), which you can then correlate with the output of `ss -plnt` to determine which service is on which interface by way of the IP to which it is assigned.  The address `0.0.0.0` or `*` (IPv4); or `::` (IPv6) indicates binding to all interfaces.

Comment: I know that, but I was wondering if lsof can do it in one go.